# Calculator VB 2010

Tags: vb.net, calculator

I have a calculator with the plus and minus buttons having this code

```
    If TextBox1.Text.Length > 3 And TextBox1.Text.Length < 999999 Then
        MsgBox("You can't add any more numbers!")
        TextBox1.Text = TextBox1.Text.Remove(TextBox1.Text.Length - 1, 1)
    Else
        int_number1 = TextBox1.Text
        TextBox1.Text = ""
        Bln_Plus = False
        Bln_Minus = True
```

However, when there is more than 3 digits in the textbox when the button is clicked  I want to make the textbox remove as many digits as it needs so there is 3 digits in the textbox
Any help??

The language is visual basic 2010

Answer (score 1):

You can do something like this:

```
TextBox1.Text = TextBox1.Text.Substring(0, 3);
```

Comment: doesnt work, still only deletes 1 digit in the textboix i want it to go straight down to 3 digits

Answer (score 0):

Actually all you really need to do is alter your range.

```
 If TextBox1.Text.Length > 3 And TextBox1.Text.Length < 999999 Then
    MsgBox("You can't add any more numbers!")
    TextBox1.Text = TextBox1.Text.Remove(TextBox1.Text.Length - 3, 999999)
Else
    int_number1 = TextBox1.Text
    TextBox1.Text = ""
    Bln_Plus = False
    Bln_Minus = True
```

Hope this helped